# Application Insight vs 2017 unhandled Exceptions

Tags: azure-application-insights

just learning about applicationInsight

I can find all kind of logging in application insight but I cannot find the unhandled exceptions.

What I did was I have just thrown an exception in my controller and looked in application insight but I could not see it.

```
 throw new NotImplementedException("my test message")
```

Does application Insights picks up exception regardless whether you log it or not and where?

I looked under failure but cannot see it.
I could see some errors there but could not expand and see the message "MyTest Message"

Is there any special settings I need to do?

Does Application insight picks up all the exceptions and where can i find them?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily find it by searching your telemetry data. From the **Dashboard** > **Search** and keep the Exception Filter on for quick search. Here you will find exception with Message.

[image]

Further click on the error message for deeper drill down.

You can also find the same from the **Exception Properties** in the Transaction details page.

[image]

Hope this helps.